# Don't see the password in inputbox but only ****

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba code for input a password to open a sheet in a workbook.

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("C21")) Is Nothing Then
Else
    Dim Wachtwoord As String
    Wachtwoord = InputBox("Geef het wachtwoord op")
    If Wachtwoord = "peflex" Then
    Sheets("Matrix").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    Else
      MsgBox ("U heeft geen toegang")
    Sheets("Menu").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    End If
    End If
```

With which code is it possible that you don't see the password but only ****

Comment: `InputBox` doesn't support password characters. I'd make a simple `UserForm` for this - add a `TextBox` and set the `PasswordChar` property to `*`.

Comment: As @comintern said, the `InputBox` does not support it. However, it is not impossible to create. Take a look at this http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=72794&p=374244#post374244 it will get you what you want, without creating a `TextBox`

Comment: @Niclas - Wow, setting a keyboard hook to avoid adding a UserForm and like 10 lines of code? That seems a little over the top considering that a UserForm *already has* keyboard events and a `TextBox` already has the functionality built in. Is this to leverage some awesome power of the `VBA.InputBox` that I missed?

Comment: I agree, nonetheless, it is possible ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I run into this a lot and I use the same code as a workaround every time. The earliest reference I can find online is from [ozgrid.com](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=72794) where the mention *Daniel Klann* as the writer.

Create a new module in your vbaproject and drop this code in:

```
'////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


'API functions to be used
Private Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long, _
    ByVal ncode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function GetModuleHandle Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetModuleHandleA" (ByVal lpModuleName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" _
    (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As Long, ByVal hmod As Long, ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SendDlgItemMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendDlgItemMessageA" _
(ByVal hDlg As Long, ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long

'Constants to be used in our API functions
Private Const EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR = &HCC
Private Const WH_CBT = 5
Private Const HCBT_ACTIVATE = 5
Private Const HC_ACTION = 0


Private hHook As Long


Public Function NewProc(ByVal lngCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Dim RetVal
    Dim strClassName As String, lngBuffer As Long

    If lngCode < HC_ACTION Then
        NewProc = CallNextHookEx(hHook, lngCode, wParam, lParam)
        Exit Function
    End If

    strClassName = String$(256, " ")
    lngBuffer = 255

    If lngCode = HCBT_ACTIVATE Then    'A window has been activated

        RetVal = GetClassName(wParam, strClassName, lngBuffer)

        If Left$(strClassName, RetVal) = "#32770" Then  'Class name of the Inputbox

            'This changes the edit control so that it display the password character *.
            'You can change the Asc("*") as you please.
            SendDlgItemMessage wParam, &H1324, EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR, Asc("*"), &H0
        End If

    End If

    'This line will ensure that any other hooks that may be in place are
    'called correctly.
    CallNextHookEx hHook, lngCode, wParam, lParam

End Function

Function InputBoxDK(Prompt, Title) As String
    Dim lngModHwnd As Long, lngThreadID As Long

    lngThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId
    lngModHwnd = GetModuleHandle(vbNullString)

    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, AddressOf NewProc, lngModHwnd, lngThreadID)

    InputBoxDK = InputBox(Prompt, Title)
    UnhookWindowsHookEx hHook

End Function
```

Then instead of

```
Wachtwoord = InputBox("Geef het wachtwoord op")
```

Use:

```
Wachtwoord = InputBoxDK("Geef het wachtwoord op")
```

You may have to save and restart excel after creating that new module. I generally name the module `m_password` and export it as a .bas file so I can reuse it. It's super handy.