# how to mask the password for 'sheet' input box

Tags: excel, vba

I protected the sheet name "Profit Loss Statement" with password. its working well but password can be visible while typing. so i wanna mask the password.
here is my code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect

Dim MySheets As String, Response As String
Dim ex As Long

MySheets = "Profit Loss Statement"
 If ActiveSheet.Name = MySheets Then
   ActiveSheet.Visible = False
    Response = InputBox("Enter password to view Profit & Loss")
      If Response = "abcd" Then   'password is abcd and to be asked
         Sheets(MySheets).Visible = True
         Application.EnableEvents = False
         Sheets(MySheets).Select
         Application.EnableEvents = True
         ActiveWorkbook.Protect
      Else
        MsgBox "Incorrect Password"
      End If
End If
Sheets(MySheets).Visible = True
ActiveWorkbook.Protect
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Don't see the password in inputbox but only \*\*\*\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40598196/dont-see-the-password-in-inputbox-but-only)

Answer (score 0):

What I know is that inputbox can not masks characters. Use an textbox in a userform, and let its property "PasswordChar" equal to *.